# Angular 2 routing: Route guard validation fails when accessing the protected url directly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

## Issue

Hello. I'm having a issue trying to implement route guards for my angular 2.2.0 application.

I've implemented a simple auth verification with a http get request and, while it works perfectly when I navigate to a guarded route in the application itself, it fails when I access the same route by the Url.

## Example

I have a route to the profile, where the logged user can access, and the unlogged user will be redirected to the route `/login`

When I access the route by the following methods:

```js
// Acessing the route by using Angular's navigate function:
<div [routerLink]="['profile']"> Profile </div>

// or
// html 
<div (click)="goToProfile()"> Profile </div>

// ts
click(){
   this._router.navigate(["profile"]);
}
```

It works perfectly. The logged user will normally access the `/profile` route, and the unlogged user will be redirected to `/login`.

But, when I access the direct route to the component:

```
http://localhost/profile
```

The validation always return false, and any user (logged or unlogged) will be redirected to `/login`.

## Relevant snippets

```js
// auth-guard.service.ts
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
          private _authService: AuthService,
          private _router: Router 
   ) { }

   canActivate(){
          if (this._authService.checkAuth()){
                return true;
          }
          this._router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;   
   }
}

// auth.service.ts
export class AuthService {
   private _isLoggedIn:boolean;
   private _userdata:any;

   constructor(@Inject(Http) private _http: Http){
       this._isLoggedIn = false;
       this._userdata = {};
       this.getProfile();
   }

   profileRequest():Observable<any>{
      return this._http.get("..").map(res => res.json());
   }

   getProfile(){
      this.profileRequest().subscribe(
         success => { 
             this._isLoggedIn = true;
             this._userdata = success.data;
         },
         error => {
             this._isLoggedIn = false;                 
         }
     );
   }

   checkAuth():boolean{
      return this._isLoggedIn;
   }
}

// app.routing.ts
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', component: AppComponent }
]);

// profile.routing.ts
export const profileRouting = RouterModule.forChild([
   { 
    path: 'profile', 
    component: ProfileContainerComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] 
   }
]);
```

I'm not sure, but maybe this is related to the http request which is made to check if the user has an valid session, since the described issue happnes on **any** guarded route.

Anyway, I'm currently stucked on this. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

## EDIT: Cause

After tracing my authentication class, I was able to figure it out what was causing this.

When I accessed the route directly through its Url, then the `checkAuth` function, at route guard, was being runned before the `getProfile`function ends. 
Since this function uses an http request, and the flow would work only if the response was received before the `checkAuth` function was called, then the process wasn't working as expected.

In other hand, when I accessed the route through the application, then the initial getProfile function was already finished, allowing to setup the variables which are used at the route guard.

## Fix

The fix (or workaround) was based on the Wuno's method for checking the authenticated user by localStorage.

After the user logged in/out, I've setted/removed the localStorage key.

This key was checked before the class variable.

```js
// auth.service.ts
checkAuth(){
    if (localStorage.getItem("USER_SESSION")){
        return true;
    }
    return this.isLoggedIn;
}
```

If you have a better approach, please send an comment and I'll update the post.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you might need to add a default value of false to private _isLoggedIn;

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this does not solve the issue. In fact, the uninitialized variable _isLoggedIn returns undefined. Just in case, I've updated my code and initialized the variable.

Comment: Can you please show your routes

Comment: Ok so it is setup as a child route? Can you also show your main routing?

Comment: Sure. Done.
Since the route guard works perfectly when I navigate through the application, I believe this is not related to my route setup, but maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok so the way you are doing this is not the way I would do it. I can show you how I set up my routes if you like. I cant for sure it will fix this but I can tell you it works for me.

Comment: Sure! I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok I provided an answer. If it helps and makes sense let me know. If not I will delete it. It might not be your issue but I assume maybe some working code can help you fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are adding `[Guard]` to the full route that is in need of protection.

So when I secure a route I add the parents to `app.routing.ts`

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full', },
    { path: '', component: PublicComponent, data: { title: 'Public Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
    { path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [Guard], data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: SECURE_ROUTES }
];



export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Make sure this line is noticed,

```
 { path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [Guard], data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: SECURE_ROUTES }
```

So I create 2 layouts

**/public/ all public components**

**/public/public.routes.ts**

**/secure/ all secure components**

**/secure/secure.routes.ts**

**Secure routes**

```
export const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'items', component: ItemsComponent },
    { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
];
```

**Main routes in app.routing.ts**

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full', },
    { path: '', component: PublicComponent, data: { title: 'Public Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
    { path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [Guard], data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: SECURE_ROUTES }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

And in the directory /layouts I create a layout that is

**/layouts/secure.component.ts
/layouts/secure.component.html
/layouts/public.component.ts
/layouts/public.component.html**

Everything is routed through the layout `public` or `secure` and `[Guard]` is on secure.

Then I handle authentication with a token in the local storage.

```
@Injectable()
export class Guard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(protected router: Router, protected auth: Auth ) {}

     canActivate() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }
        // not logged in so redirect to login page
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Once I set my app up like this I put all my routes that need to be secure in the secure directory and the public routes in public. Then I create their routes in the public.routes.ts file or the secure.routes.ts file which are in their respective directory.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure it out what was the cause of my issue after reading your code.

When I accessed the routing navigating through the application, the route guard worked correctly because it was already initialized.

But when I accessed the route directly by its url, then the route guard check was failing because it was being called before the http response regarding the authentication was completed.

The  workaround was to set the localStorage variable after the user logon, and check for it at the route guard verification (exactly as you do).